# Combined vectorized functions in Numba

Tags: gpu, vectorization, numba, dispatch, numpy-ufunc

I'm using Numba (version 0.37.0) to optimize code for GPU.
I would like to use combined vectorized functions (using @vectorize decorator of Numba).

Imports & Data:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
from numba import vectorize, guvectorize

angles = np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi, 10)
coords = np.stack([np.cos(angles), np.sin(angles)], axis=1)
```

This works as expected:

```
@guvectorize(['(float32[:], float32[:])'], '(i)->()', target='cuda')
def l2_norm(vec, out):
    acc = 0.0
    for value in vec:
        acc += value**2
    out[0] = sqrt(acc)

l2_norm(coords)
```

Output:

```
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)
```

But I'd like to avoid using that "for" inside "l2_norm" by calling another vectorized function.

I've tried this:

```
@vectorize(["float32(float32)"], target="cuda")
def power(value):
    return value**2

@guvectorize(['(float32[:], float32[:])'], '(i)->()', target='cuda')
def l2_norm_power(vec, out):
    acc = 0.0
    acc = power(vec)
    acc = acc.sum()
    out[0] = sqrt(acc)

l2_norm_power(coords)
```

But raises TypingError:

```
TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'power': cannot determine Numba type of <class  
'numba.cuda.dispatcher.CUDAUFuncDispatcher'>
```

Any idea about how to perform this combination?

Any suggestion about other way to optimize l2_norm with Numba?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can only call `device=True` functions from other cuda functions:

> [3.13.2. Example: Calling Device Functions](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/ufunc.html#example-calling-device-functions)
>
> All CUDA ufunc kernels have the ability to call other CUDA device functions:
>
> ```py
>  from numba import vectorize, cuda
>  # define a device function
>  @cuda.jit('float32(float32, float32, float32)', device=True, inline=True)
>  def cu_device_fn(x, y, z):
>      return x ** y / z
>  # define a ufunc that calls our device function
>  @vectorize(['float32(float32, float32, float32)'], target='cuda')
>  def cu_ufunc(x, y, z):
>      return cu_device_fn(x, y, z)
> ```

Note that you can call `cuda.jit` functions with `device`:

```
@cuda.jit(device=True)
def sum_of_squares(arr):
    acc = 0
    for item in arr:
        acc += item ** 2
    return acc

@nb.guvectorize(['(float32[:], float32[:])'], '(i)->()', target='cuda')
def l2_norm_power(vec, out):
    acc = sum_of_squares(vec)
    out[0] = sqrt(acc)

l2_norm_power(coords)
```

But that probably defeats the purpose of splitting it.

Since `numba.vectorize` doesn't support `device` that's not possible for these functions. But that's a good thing because `vectorize` allocates an array to put the values in, that's an unnecessary intermediate array and allocating arrays on the GPU is also very inefficient (and forbidden in numba):

> [3.5.5. Numpy support](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/cudapysupported.html#numpy-support)
>
> Due to the CUDA programming model, dynamic memory allocation inside a kernel is inefficient and is often not needed. Numba disallows any memory allocating features. This disables a large number of NumPy APIs. For best performance, users should write code such that each thread is dealing with a single element at a time.

---

Given all that I would simply use your original approach:

```
@guvectorize(['(float32[:], float32[:])'], '(i)->()', target='cuda')
def l2_norm(vec, out):
    acc = 0.0
    for value in vec:
        acc += value**2
    out[0] = sqrt(acc)

l2_norm(coords)
```

Comment: Let's say you wanted to perform quicksort. Would you then just hard-code and copy-paste the sorting code as many times as it's needed in the top-level function?

Comment: Or is the example you gave with `cuda.jit(device=True)` and `@guvectorize` OK in terms of efficiency?

Comment: @Sterling I cannot really say. I haven't worked with numba in a while and am not exactly sure what you ask. Maybe better to ask a new question with your explicit details? :)